# Use Windows Desktop as Thin Client Server

Tags: windows, authentication, desktop, vpn, thin-client

I want to use my Windows Desktop (XP, Windows7, , Win 10, Linux) as Thin Client Server.
It should be able to give a simultaneous log in session to 5-6 persons using thin client or Internet.
Basically, I want it to make a server, for a community group, which can use the same machine in a room for development. To give everyone more flexibility, I would like to give them another option, to use same machine to log in (With given username and password) and  use it as virtual desktop (as in case of Citrix) in a simultaneous log in manner.

If I can Internet simultaneous log in Idea, It will be a big help.

Please leave your suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I have got to the bottom of it,
but you sure can install windows7 or windows server 2008, 
don't know about later versions.
And simultaneously keep few users connected with RemoteControl (msdtc) to the same machine.

Comment: I want each user to have a separate desktop to work on application. This means when they will connect they will get a new windows.